# is there any way to redirect domain to two different ips

Tags: windows, networking, server, dns

In my friend's office he has 2 public ips and its configured in fortigate with load balancing. Also he has 1 web server and his clients accessing the portal with isp1 primarily and clients sometimes accessing the portal using isp2 also if isp1 goes down. but every time he is informing the clients to use alternate 1 if any 1 isp goes down. if we buy 1 domain from registrar, can we redirect that domain to these isp1 ip or isp2 ip if any 1 goes down.
Or any other way to switch the ip to reach webserver without informing clients.

Thanks in advance.
Kumar B

Comment: read both answers and comments: https://serverfault.com/questions/563835/is-round-robin-dns-a-possible-solution-for-high-availability

Answer (score 0):

Buying a Domain and redirecting to isp1 or isp2 is a good idea but there will be a little downtime till you switch the isp.

If you are serving static content try using a CDN to cache all your server files so that it will be serving to the clients even if your isp1 or isp2 id down.